# Cakephp not allowing login with any authentication

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, blowfish

I'm attempting to use cakephp for the first time and the code I've written isn't allowing for me to log any users in. The creation of users works just fine as I was able to query my database and output the username and hashed password. I'm not sure if I'm just missing a line of code somewhere or if I perhaps am not making the password field in my database large enough. I have fiddled with my database variables but altering the size and type both don't seem to help.

AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller 
{
public $helpers = array('Html');

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'login',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'home', 
            'action' => 'index', 'home'
        ),
        'Auth' => array('authorize' => 'Controller'),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array('passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish')
        )
    )
);

public function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    $this->set('loggedin', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
}

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    if(($this->Auth->user('id')) === $user['user_id'])
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please log in to view this page'));
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

My UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('HTML', 'Form');

public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));
}

public function add()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $this->User->create();

        if($this->User->save($this->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Created new user'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Could not create new user. Please try again.'));
    }
}

public function login()
{
    //$this->set('allUsers', $this->User->query("SELECT `User`.`user_id`, `User`.`username`, 
    //`User`.`password` FROM `ead44db`.`users` AS `User` WHERE 1 = 1"));

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if($this->Auth->login())
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect user name or password, please try again.'));
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

}

My User model:

```
<?php

App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel
{
public $validate = array('username' => array('required' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty')), 
    'password' => array('required' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty')));

/*public $hasMany = array('Review' => array('className' => 'Review', 'foreignKey' => 'reviewer_id'),
    'Message' => array('className' => 'Message', 'foreignKey' => 'user_to_id'),
    'Message' => array('className' => 'Message', 'foreignKey' => 'user_from_id'),
    'Comment' => array('className' => 'Comment', 'foreignKey' => 'commenter_id'));*/

public $hasMany = array('Review', 'Message', 'Comment');

public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    if(isset($this->data['User']['password']))
    {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data['User']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
}

?>
```

And my database table for users:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username varchar(50) UNIQUE,
password TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I'm currently having the exact same problem. I'm beginning to think that it's a bug. If I compare the hashes manually, I can see that I entered the correct password, yet the login doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in the BlowfishPasswordHash.php

Reads

```
public function check($password, $hashedPassword) {
    return $hashedPassword === Security::hash($password, 'blowfish', $hashedPassword);
}
```

It's passing the hashed version of the password from the user record in the database as the 'salt'. Which makes no sense.

Should read

```
public function check($password, $hashedPassword) {
   return $hashedPassword === Security::hash($password, 'blowfish', false);
}
```

Which is consistent with the 'hash' method that generates the password hash to begin with.

The bug appears to be limited to the 2.5.x Cake release.

Answer (score 0):

```
public $components = array(                                                 
                        'Auth' => array(
                            'authenticate' => array(                                    
                                'Form' => array(
                                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                                )
                            ),
                            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'index'),
                            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index', 'home'),
                            'authorize' => array('Controller')
                        ),
                        'Session'   
                    );
```